# Как узнать длину массива char с пробелами

Tags: c++, char

Как узнать длину массива?

```
sizeof(ch)
```

не подходит потому что, когда он идет пробел, то на этом все заканчивается

Comment: `sizeof` вообще никак не учитывает значение переменной. Он опирается только на **тип**. Опишите проблему более конкретно.

Comment: ++ Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Для определения длины сишной строки есть стандартная функция `strlen`.

Answer (score 2):

Если длину **массива** в виде строки, то:

```
#include <string.h>
char charArr[] = "string";
strlen(charArr); // 6, размер самой строки
strlen(charArr) + 1; // 7, размер массива с символом окончания строки
```

UPD:

Если длину **массива** в виде int array[]:

```
return sizeof(array)/sizeof(array);
```

Если это **массив динамический**, и **нет критерия конца массива**, то ответ - никак.

Comment: У массива размер 7 байт. А 6 это длина строки без терминирующего нуля.

Comment: @alexolut ихть, в вопросе не только строки, точно

Answer (score 1):

И при чём здесь плюсы?
Если нужно работать со строками, то
`std::string::length` в помощь.
Если с массивами, то `std::vector`